# How I keep numbers stored in a loop

Tags: c++

I am making a program that needs the user to input 2 numbers. Once they do this, the code must ask them to enter a third number, and it must keep looping until the user inputs a 0. I have got the whole code to work, however when i enter the third number, it doesnt add on the previous number. For example, if i enter 3 the first time and 4 the second time, you would think the answer would be 7, but it just uses the latest number you input and doesnt add them up.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    float c = 1;

    int e = 3;
    cout << "Please enter 2 numbers" << endl;
    float a;
    float b;
    cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    float x = a + b;
    float y = (a + b) / 2;
    cout << "The sum of your 2 numbers is " << x << endl;
    cout << "The mean of your 2 numbers is " << y << endl;


    while (true)
    {
        if (c > 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter the third number" << endl;
            cin >> c;
            float newtotal = x + c;
            cout << "The sum of the new numbers is " << newtotal << endl;
            cout << "The mean of the new numbers is " << newtotal / e++ << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }



    cin.get();
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is going on inside of your loop? In `if` block, to be exact.

Comment: where did you define y?

Comment: I forgot to include it in the snippet. I'll edit it now

Comment: You should also include a copy of the console display showing the numbers you entered and the output the program printed. Then we wouldn't have make so many guesses about what you are trying to tell us happened. In particular, if your _first_ number was 3 and the _second_ was 4, the program looks like it would print 7 before it even started the loop. So I'm guessing you mean that 3 was the first "third" number and 4 was the second "third" number (see a problem with your use of the word "third" here?). A complete printout would clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually not totally understanding your statement. What I assume here is that you want to calculate the sum and avg of all the numbers entered. In that way, your most critical mistake is the scope of `newtotal`. x will always be the sum of `a` and `b`, so `newtotal` will always be `a + b + c` where c is the last number you've entered.

Plus, your program would still add the 0 that indicates termination because it will only break at the next iteration.

And I really don't know why you need the last 3 lines of code in `main()`.

My version of the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int e = 3, a, b, x, c;
    cout << "Please enter 2 numbers" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    x = a + b;
    cout << "The sum of your 2 numbers is " << x << endl;
    cout << "The mean of your 2 numbers is " << (float)x/2 << endl;


    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter the next number" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        x += c;
        if (c == 0)
            break;
        cout << "The sum of the new numbers are " << x << endl;
        cout << "The mean of the new numbers are " << (float)x / e++ << endl;
    }
    // I don't know why you need the code here
}
```